# Contour Plotting on a map: Error using inpolygon (line 65) Polygon must be defined by vectors (XV, YV)

Tags: matlab, dictionary, polygon, contour

Trying to plot gridded data from .mat file onto a contour map.  I have run the same exact code for two different datasets with no problem, but get the following error message when I run it for the Atlantic-East Pacific basin:

Error using inpolygon (line 65) Polygon must be defined by vectors (XV, YV).

I get about 10 other error messages in addition to the one above...the message above is the first error message.

What I want to do is take the data included in the variable Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC for all longitudes and latitudes for the first time step, which looks like this:

Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC(:,:,1)

The map and data stretch from 140W to the Prime Meridian, from 0N to 30N.  The resolution is 0.25 deg x 0.25 deg, so there are 561 rows and 121 columns for the Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC data.  In other words, Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC has dimensions of 561 x 121 x 306 (there are 306 timesteps).

Below is my code-any help you can provide will be great!

```
% filename = sample_mapping_TRMM_ATL_EPAC.m
%
% Purpose:  This file incorporates clustered event power TRMM data from the 
% ATL_EPAC basin and plots it on a map using filled contours, with a 
% log-scaled contour bar.  These plots allow for much easier spatial analysis % of the clusters, and to see how cluster size and power varies by rain rate.
%
% Author:  Kevin Quinn
%
% Outside functions called:  
%   setMap_ATL_EPAC
%   makeColorMap
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% clear workspace, data, and any open figures

clear all;
close all;
clc;

% for rain rates from 0.1 to 0.5mm/hr

for rain = 1:5;
Nrain = sprintf('%01d',rain);

% load the relevant datafiles, and cycle through files denoted by rain rate
filename = (['2004_TRMM_TROPICS_Watts_Maps_pt_' num2str(Nrain) 'mmhr_ATL_EPAC.mat']);
load(filename)

% assign lat/lon to each grid cell
gLat = 0:0.25:30;  % 0N to 30N, 0.25 deg resolution
gLon = -140:0.25:0;  % 140W to Prime Meridian, 0.25 deg resolution
[gLat,gLon] = meshgrid(gLat,gLon); % mesh the lat/lon grids together 

% call the setMap function to create the map for the ATL_EPAC basin
setMap_ATL_EPAC

data = Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC(:,:,1);  % rename cluster watts to data to make code-writing easy
contours = [10^0 10^1 10^2 10^3 10^4 10^5 10^6];  % set the contours for the colorbar

% most important step...overlay contoured cluster watts data
contourfm(gLat,gLon,log(data),log(contours));  

% next two lines:  place continents/land back on map
coast = load('coast');
geoshow(coast.lat,coast.long,'Color','black');

% customize the colorbar, axes, and save figure as dpng file
cb = colorbar('FontSize',12,'XTick',log(contours),'XTickLabel',contours,'Location','southoutside');%'FontSize',12,);
cMap = makeColorMap([1 1 1],[0 0 1],[1 0 0],30);
colormap(cMap);
caxis(log([contours(1) contours(length(contours))]));
set(get(cb,'XLabel'),'String','Event Power (GW)','FontSize',14,'FontWeight', ...
    'bold');
t = title(['TRMM-3B42 Clusters, Rain Rate GTE 0.' num2str(Nrain) 'mm/hr, 1 May 2004']);
set(t,'FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold');
eval(['print -dpng Sample_TRMM_Cluster_Map_pt_' num2str(Nrain) 'mmhr_ATL_EPAC.png']) 

clear filename data Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC  % clear out data to prevent overwriting

end
```

Data file:  look at Watts_Map_ATL_EPAC...

Comment: I see no call to `inpolygon` in your code.

Comment: To be honest, me neither.  New to MATLAB's Mapping Toolbox.  I tried running the code all the way up to but not including the "contourfm(..." line, and it ran fine until I ran the "contourfm(..." line, so I suspect it has something to do with that function.

Comment: I also see no line 65 in your code. This error message is probably being thrown by a function called by your code. Please include the complete error message despite it being 10 lines long, so that we know which line in your code is calling the error generating function.

Comment: Have you checked if there' any NaN's in the shapefile that might be bothering?

Comment: Error messages broken into a couple parts:  Error using inpolygon (line 65)
Polygon must be defined by vectors (XV, YV).

Error in adjustContourTopology>traceAllSectors (line 361)
    S(k).ContainsMax = inpolygon(xmax, ymax, S(k).X, S(k).Y);

Error in adjustContourTopology>analyzeTopology (line 148)
[S, B] = traceAllSectors(x, y, xlimit, ylimit, xmax, ymax);

Error in adjustContourTopology (line 86)
[C, B, S] = analyzeTopology(x, y, xlimit, ylimit, xmax, ymax);

Error in contourIntrinsic>fixTopology (line 365)
    [x, y, xp, yp] = adjustContourTopology( ...

Comment: Error in contourIntrinsic (line 122)
    [L, P] = fixTopology(L, xLimit, yLimit, xmax, ymax);

Error in geocontours (line 138)
    [L, P] = contourIntrinsic(Z, levels, R.RasterInterpretation, edgefix);

Error in internal.mapgraph.GeographicContourGroup/getFillPolygons (line 100)
               [h.pContourLines, h.pFillPolygons] ...

Error in internal.mapgraph.ContourGroup/refresh (line 439)
                S = h.getFillPolygons();

Comment: Error in contourm (line 116)
refresh(h)

Error in contourfm (line 36)
        contourm(varargin{:},'Fill','on','DefaultLineColor','black');

Error in Sample_Mapping_TRMM_ATL_EPAC (line 43)
contourfm(gLat,gLon,log(data),log(contours));

Comment: I don't see any NaNs too...thanks everyone for your help though!

Comment: Is it possible that you share the shapefile/data vector?

Comment: Really dumb question but I have to ask...how can I upload the .mat file here?